# Is Firedatabase.SetPersistent (true) minimiza downloading data?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Is this guarantee to download the data only one time across the App life/App restarts even if the user has good connection?

N.B: The official docs isn't clear ( at least for me) at this point.

> By enabling persistence, any data that the Firebase Realtime Database client would sync while online persists to disk and is available offline, even when the user or operating system restarts the app. This means your app works as it would online by using the local data stored in the cache. Listener callbacks will continue to fire for local updates.

Answer (score 2):

The sole goal of enabling persistence is to ensure that the app continues to work, even when the user starts it when they don't have a connection to the Firebase servers.

The client **does** send tree of hash values of its restored local state to the server when it connects, which the server then uses to only send the modified segments back. But there is no guarantee on how much data this sends or saves.

If you want to learn more about what Firebase actually does under the hood, I highly recommend [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and studying its output on logcat.

For more on the topic, see these questions on [Firebase's synchronization strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+delta+sync).

Comment: I will consider to view the firebase Log. Another related question , If I call the value of  'users/' many times, will firebase cache it and return data from cache or not?

Comment: I'd recommend turning on debug logging and checking. :) (Hint: it depends on whether there's already an active listener on the same location).

Comment: I had tried to check log many times but I got very few lines, I used the word 'Firebase' as tag. So I think that I need help about What is the TAG /s that firebase use in logging?